# Git: How to cherry-pick a commit without all previous history

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I want to add some specific changes from a specific commit in my `current` repo to my `upstream` repo.

Running something like this:
`git push upstream <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>`

adds the commit plus all the previous changes

Running something like

```
git checkout -b new-branch 
git pull <remote> <upstream branch> branch is
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
git push <remote> new-branch
```

Also writes all the previous changes.

I just want to write the specific changes of that commit into the `upstream` repo, so it does not include the changes made by the previous commits in my `current` repo, which are not in the `upstream`.

There's lots of info on StackOverflow about `cherry-pick` and `rebase` but none answers this very specific question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the local branch out of the remote branch in upstream repo and then cherry pick.

Assuming "upstream" is the name of your upstream remote, you can do the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b new-branch upstream/<upstream branch>
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
git push upstream new-branch
```

You can check the name of the upstream repo using

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: Super! This worked. The only thing I had to add was `git cherry-pick --continue` after resolving some conflicts before pushing it upstream. Thank you so much, as nobody could give an answer to this for hours. Your solution is the best.